# Filter and sort moderator candidates

Tags: feature-request, voting, election

When choosing moderator candidates to vote for, I find myself going back and forth between the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) and the various user pages (which I keep open in other windows/tabs).

This is a pain because, the candidates are displayed in a random order (which is otherwise good), and I have to wade through a couple-dozen candidate-blurbs each time -- even though I might have whittled my choices down to 4 or 5.

**Requested feature:**
  It would be great if the election page had a ***Filter out*** button next to each candidate.  When pressed it:

1. Hides that candidate's entry.
2. When the election page is revisited, that candidate is not shown.

---

If we could also filter by: a badge list, votes up, votes down, question votes, answer votes, days visited, number of answers, et cetera, that would be super. :)

Comment: Right click on username -> open in new tab. I agree that showing a few more statistics would be helpful.

Comment: @Pubby, I guess I didn't make the question clear. I already do that.

Comment: Have you tried [elections.stackexchange.com](http://elections.stackexchange.com)?  It has various filtering options and displays a lot of statistics on the candidates.

Comment: @hammar, No, I forgot about that page.  Now I have **3 types** of pages to switch between!  ;) ... ... And it has the same "needle in a haystack" issue that the election page has.  That is, great info, but needs filtering.

Comment: Hmm, I'll make a note with regard to improving the [election stats](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) page.

Answer (score 4):

I finally published my userscript that **sorts and helps filter candidates**.
For more information, visit the *Stack Apps* page; it's: [Stack Exchange, Election Assistant](https://stackapps.com/questions/6692/stack-exchange-election-assistant).
Or [get it from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-Election-Assistant).

The script:

- Lists candidates in **sorted order**. Find him/her in a repeatable, predictable, location every page visit.
- Click on a jump-table row to **instantly scroll to that candidate.**
- **Save a bookmark** that opens the page **to that candidate's entry**, every time.
- **Like, Hide, or Reject** a candidate.  Save your data between page visits and between tabs.
- Provides **direct links** to a candidate's entry on the [*Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics* (SEMC)](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#music.stackexchange) page.
- If you open one of those SEMC links, **the script automatically scrolls to the targeted user** (even while the SEMC page loads and settles).
- If you downvoted a candidate in the primary, then those users are auto-rejected when you visit the primary page.
- Works on all SE Election pages. <sub>(Not tested on Non English sites, but should work except for any formatting issues.)</sub>

[image: Filtering in action]